# Can localize in hundreds of languages but can only set phone in 38

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, settings

When I come to localize in Xcode there is a drop down menu of hundreds of languages (I havn't counted them) But when I go to settings on the iPhone to test them there are only 38. Is it possible to download and supplement these preloaded 38? It would seem pretty pointless to localise an app for a language if you can't then set that language in the settings. For instance hindi does not seem to be available.

Thanks for any help

Silas

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone settings only lists the 38 because these are the languages Apple has localized the iPhone system apps and such with.  The good news is in iOS 8 you will be able to localize your app to any of the languages, even the ones apple hasn't gotten to yet.

BONUS: Hindi is added as a system language in iOS 8

Reference link: http://www.ibabbleon.com/copywriter-translator/2014/06/new-xcode-6-localization-ios-yosemite/